# An anomaly while calculating percentage increase. How to proceed?

Tags: tcl, percentage, divide-by-zero

I am using the following formula to find the % of increase,

```
( (final_amount - original_amount) / original_amount ) * 100
```

My original amount is zero and final amount is, say, 1000. I am getting a divide-by-zero error.

and what happens if my final amount is also 0 ?

How do I go about finding the %increase ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple: you can't!

You are applying the reverse of this equation:

```
original + original * amount/100 = final
```

where your unknown is *amount*. However, when *original* is *0*, the left side of the equation is always *0* and you have *0 = final*, whatever *amount* is.

---

**Edit**

If you want an increase from 0 to *whatever* to be seen as *100*, you can use an `if` statement:

```
if { $origina_amount == 0 } {
    set increase 100
} else {
    set increase [expr {($final_amount - $origina_amont) / $original_amount * 100}]
}
```

Comment: can I make the %increase to 100 ? infinity on a scale of 100 is 100.

Comment: Distinguish the two cases using an `if` statement. I'm editing my answer to put some code.

Comment: One liner version: `set increase [expr {$original_amount ? ($final_amount - $original_amount) / $original_amount * 100 : 100}]`